# Adding up the numeric parts of a matched string in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is hard to explain in so I will try and demonstrate, this is all done in an MS SQL stored procedure.

I have a list of records

- 10 foos
- 15 foos
- 35 bahs
- 98 foobahs
- 10 foos
- 35 foos
- 35 bahs
- 99 foobahs
- 99 foobahs
- Geoff
- Brian
- Geoff
- James 99
- James 99
- James

I have a script which currently converts the records to:

> 2x 10 foos + 15 foos + 3x 35 bahs + 98 foobahs + 2x 99foobahs + 2x Geoff + Brain + 2x James 99 + James

What I need it to is to add up all the similar records where theree is a numeric value at the start of the string, resulting in

> 35 foos + 105 foos + 296 foobahs + 2x Geoff + Brain + 2x James 99 + James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a [table variable](http://odetocode.com/articles/365.aspx) with columns **Name** and **Quantity** *yet before processing* of initial bulleted list
2. During processing of bulleted list, add every item with normalized name (foo, bah, brian, geoff, ...) as a separate record into the table variable
3. you get the result as `SELECT Name, SUM(Quantity) FROM @tableVar GROUP BY Name`
4. build requested string from the above result

feel free to ask if anything is unclear

Answer (score 0):

It would be better that you split the number and the item and store them in the table as seperate columns. String manipulation is not good in SQL server. With that said, you can try the following query

This query splits the values into number and item, then sums up the similar items and joins them to a single value. Very ugly, but hope it works

```
;WITH items
AS
(
       SELECT CAST(
                CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',columnName)>1 
                    THEN SUBSTRING(columnName,1,PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',columnName))
                ELSE '1' END 
                AS INT) 
            AS Number,
                CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',columnName)>1 
                    THEN SUBSTRING(columnName,PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',columnName),LEN(columnName))
                ELSE columnName END
            AS Item  
       FROM theTable  

)
SELECT CAST(SUM(Number) AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' ' + item  + ' +' AS 'text()'
FROM items
GROUP BY item
FOR XML Path('')
```